# Proof verification that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a, b- k \cdot a )$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm

> We wish to prove that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a, b- k \cdot a )$, where $a,b, k$ are integers.

For any divisor $d|a$ and $d|b$ then we also have that for all integers $x,y$ we have $$d|(ax+by)$$ now let $x=-k$ and $y=1$ then $d|(b-ka)$. I still have to make the step to the gcd now, since I prove this for general divisors, is my proof also valid for the gcd? this only would mean that $d$ is the greatest such integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the two sets of divisors are the same, their maximum is too.

Comment: Since it holds for arbitrary $d$, right?

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Yep.

Answer (score 1):

What you proved so far is $d \mid \gcd(a,b) \implies d \mid \gcd(a, b-ka)$

If you can prove  $d \mid \gcd(a,b-ka) \implies d \mid \gcd(a,b)$ it will follow that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a, b-ka)$.

Proof. 
\begin{align}
   d \mid \gcd(a,b-ka) 
   &\implies (d\mid a) \ \wedge \ (d\mid b-ka) \\
   &\implies (d\mid a) \ \wedge \ (d \mid b - ka + ka) \\
   &\implies (d\mid a) \ \wedge \ (d \mid b)
\end{align}